# How to send/receive data from a usb port with python

Tags: python, io, usb, external, fpga

I am designing an FPGA for a college project and we need to send data to an FPGA, so we wanted to use USB cords and a python program to manage sending/receiving/displaying information on the computer sending/receiving data from the FPGA.
I've never really written anything to send data to external devices other than when using putty and an atmel avr microcontroller for a previous class, so i'm not familiar with how USB works. If anyone knows how to do this in python, as well as any issues i need to be aware of that would be great. I'm using Python 3.7 and working on a windows 10 laptop.

Edit: some clarification on the project itself. We are using the FPGA as an encoder. The fpga will have modules that perform the encoding and other stuff, but the python program itself only needs to ask the user for an encoding method and get said data to be encoded, then append bits to the data that will allow the FPGA to identify the encoding method, then send the data out to a usb.

Comment: Does your FPGA have a processor with a Python interpreter and a complete USB stack? If not I suggest you go back to using RS323 (Or as you call it: putty).

Comment: As Oldfart suggests, then use [RS-232](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232) for a start.  It is a good opportunity to learn an old, but still very useful communication standard, and you can debug problems with a simple oscilloscope.  For connection from the PC to the FPGA, take a look at cables that use the [FTDI 232R](https://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT232R.htm), like this [cable](https://uk.farnell.com/ftdi/usb-rs232-we-1800-bt-3-3/cable-usb-rs232-conv-wire-end/dp/2352006), or just do the wiring yourself using a FTDI 232 board you can buy on e.g. Ebay.